# Edittext text select-all and then type first letter will not displayed

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

There is an awkward scenario happening in my application.

My application has functionality like `EditText` for the price, where you tap on it will select all text, then you can enter a price. When user clicking on `EditText`, it is selecting all text but, when the user enters any text, the first number will not be displayed. Then another number will be displayed properly. I have added `TextChangeListner` and try to figure out but I am getting **0** `CharSequence` while users enter the first character.

I have inputfilter for `EditText`. Check below code for editfilter.

```
public static class InputFilterForDoubleMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private double min, max;

    public InputFilterForDoubleMinMax(double min, double max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterForDoubleMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Double.parseDouble(min);
        this.max = Double.parseDouble(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            String temp = dest.toString() + source.toString();
            if (source.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(".")) {
                return "";
            } else if (temp.toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
                temp = temp.toString().substring(temp.toString().indexOf(",") + 1);
                if (temp.length() > 2) {
                    return "";
                }
            }


            double input = Double.parseDouble(dest.toString().replace(",", ".").replace("€", "") + source.toString().replace(",", ".").replace("€", ""));
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(double a, double b, double c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. the issue was due to logic implemented inside input filter.

Following is my updated code input filter.

```
  public static class InputFilterForDoubleMinMax implements InputFilter {

        private double min, max;

        public InputFilterForDoubleMinMax(double min, double max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public InputFilterForDoubleMinMax(String min, String max) {
            this.min = Double.parseDouble(min);
            this.max = Double.parseDouble(max);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                String temp;
                if (dstart == 0) {
                    temp = source.toString();
                } else {
                    temp = dest.toString() + source.toString();
                }
                if (source.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(".")) {
                    return "";
                } else if (temp.toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
                    temp = temp.toString().substring(temp.toString().indexOf(",") + 1);
                    if (temp.length() > 2) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }


                double input;
                if (dstart == 0) {
                    input = Double.parseDouble(source.toString().replace(",", ".").replace("€", ""));

                } else {
                    input = Double.parseDouble(dest.toString().replace(",", ".").replace("€", "") + source.toString().replace(",", ".").replace("€", ""));
                }

                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            }
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(double a, double b, double c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```
package com.imrhk.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    editText.selectAll();
                }
            }
        });

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                if(editText.getSelectionStart() != -1) {
                    //editText.setText("");
                    editText.setSelected(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

R.layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

edit:

Add this as filter

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if(String.valueOf(source).equals(".") && String.valueOf(dest).equals("100"))    //replace it with maxed value
                    return "";
                try {
                    Float f = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(dest) + String.valueOf(source.toString()));
                    if (f < 0.0f || f > 100.0f) //replace it with max/min value
                        return "";
                    return null;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }});
```

Comment: if you use `inputType="numberDecimal"` you will have to use only range filter to filter out.

Comment: Doing samething